# backup AWS Custom JSON

Tags: aws-opsworks, aws-cli

I would like to backup a number of the AWS Stacks' Custom JSON files. I can't seem to find an API that will extract them for me. Is there an applicable API available? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

I Assume you are using CloudFormation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-get-template.html